# How can I use and SSAS dimension to build a generic Year To Date measure?

Tags: ssas, cube, dimensions

I'm trying to emulate the method laid out by Russo, Ferrari and Webb in *Expert Cube Development* to build a dimension that reports (among other things) a Year To Date version of every measure in the cube, and I can't seem to make it work.  I'm hoping someone here will have experience with this technique (or can point me to a better one) and can tell me where I'm going wrong.

I'm trying to translate this piece of MDX code that appears in the calculation section of their sample cube into my cube:

```
SCOPE ( 
[Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS,
[Date].[Date].MEMBERS ); 

( [DateTool].[Aggregation].[Year To Date] )
      = Aggregate(
                 { [DateTool].[Aggregation].DefaultMember } *
                   PeriodsToDate(
                                [Date].[Calendar].[Year],
                                [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember
                 ) );

END SCOPE;
```

Here is my version:

```
 SCOPE (
 [Time Order Date].[Fiscal Date].MEMBERS,
 [Time Order Date].[Date].MEMBERS
 );

 (     [Time Calculations].[Calculation].[Year to Date] )
      = Aggregate(
                 { [Time Calculations].DefaultMember } *
                   PeriodsToDate(
                                [Time Order Date].[Fiscal Date].[Year],
                                [Time Order Date].[Fiscal Date].CurrentMember
                 ) );

 END SCOPE;
```

This differs from the Russo et al version only by substituting our time dimension names for theirs.

FWIW, I have built a Time Calculations dimension following Russo et al's DateTool dimension.

The particular formulation that you see above returns "VALUE!" when I try to view it, and I don't quite see what might be wrong with it.

FWIW, if instead of trying to perform the aggregation, I simply assign the value of 10 in the above (i.e. I define the measure like this:

```
 (     [Time Calculations].[Calculation].[Year to Date] )
      = 10
 ;
```

), just to see the substitution being made, I get the value "20".  I have no idea what is going on double the static value.

Any help would be appreciated.  --sw

Comment: Is `Calculation` the only attribute in your `Time Calculations` dimension? Have you defined a member of this attribute as the defaultmember before your `SCOPE` statement? How does your time dimension look like?

Comment: Yes, Calculation is the only attribute in Time Calculations.  I have defined "Real Value" as the defaultmember of Time Calculations (so defined in the designer as opposed to the MDX script...should that matter?).  How much detail should I include about the time dimension.  It has a date primary key and a fiscal and calendar hierarchies.